# Flot with JSON not working properly

Tags: jquery, json, flot

Hello I am having some problems loading the Data section into Flot when I load from Jquery however when I manually type in the data values it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var kcArray = [];


        function onDataReceived(series) {

            $.each(series, function(i, marker) {
            var dq = [[new Date(1346976001000), 3904.8408203125], [new Date(1346976011000), 3919.70678710938], [new Date(1346976021000), 3933.97265625], [new Date(1346976031000), 3956.583984375], [new Date(1346976041000), 3975.85083007813], [new Date(1346976051000), 3960.72924804688], [new Date(1346976061000), 3962.5751953125], [new Date(1346976071000), 4001.56372070313], [new Date(1346976081000), 4005.63549804688], [new Date(1346976091000), 3994.11499023438], [new Date(1346976101000), 3992.95141601563], [new Date(1346976111000), 3972.32470703125], [new Date(1346976121000), 3957.19848632813], [new Date(1346976131000), 3943.83935546875], [new Date(1346976141000), 3939.63305664063], [new Date(1346976151000), 3944.61474609375], [new Date(1346976161000), 3960.82592773438], [new Date(1346976171000), 3967.658203125], [new Date(1346976181000), 3975.17578125], [new Date(1346976191000), 4001.0302734375], [new Date(1346976201000), 4015.51171875], [new Date(1346976211000), 4004.38500976563], [new Date(1346976221000), 3974.08227539063], [new Date(1346976231000), 3941.20751953125], [new Date(1346976241000), 3936.21801757813], [new Date(1346976251000), 3945.08984375], [new Date(1346976261000), 3933.44970703125], [new Date(1346976271000), 3933.52319335938], [new Date(1346976281000), 3939.19970703125], [new Date(1346976291000), 3954.7646484375], [new Date(1346976301000), 3962.11254882813], [new Date(1346976311000), 3956.17358398438], [new Date(1346976321000), 3992.56396484375], [new Date(1346976331000), 4008.015625], [new Date(1346976341000), 4039.65112304688], [new Date(1346976351000), 4045.77319335938], [new Date(1346976361000), 4010.93359375], [new Date(1346976371000), 3990.35888671875], [new Date(1346976381000), 3984.05810546875], [new Date(1346976391000), 3986.58666992188], [new Date(1346976401000), 3988.79345703125], [new Date(1346976411000), 3996.03857421875], [new Date(1346976421000), 4017.88989257813], [new Date(1346976431000), 4011.49584960938], [new Date(1346976441000), 4031.03857421875], [new Date(1346976451000), 4038.71362304688], [new Date(1346976461000), 4048.50927734375], [new Date(1346976471000), 4036.84204101563], [new Date(1346976481000), 3998.3544921875], [new Date(1346976491000), 3981.95434570313], [new Date(1346976501000), 3980.75952148438], [new Date(1346976511000), 3961.21630859375], [new Date(1346976521000), 3966.2451171875], [new Date(1346976531000), 3969.21728515625], [new Date(1346976541000), 3981.84155273438], [new Date(1346976551000), 3988.89111328125], [new Date(1346976561000), 4003.67626953125], [new Date(1346976571000), 4010.57202148438], [new Date(1346976581000), 3994.47241210938], [new Date(1346976591000), 3968.3349609375], [new Date(1346976601000), 3971.16723632813], [new Date(1346976611000), 3967.21752929688], [new Date(1346976621000), 3961.94604492188], [new Date(1346976631000), 3956.22509765625], [new Date(1346976641000), 3958.71850585938], [new Date(1346976651000), 3942.47021484375], [new Date(1346976661000), 3945.68188476563], [new Date(1346976671000), 3962.16723632813], [new Date(1346976681000), 3981.14794921875], [new Date(1346976691000), 3999.26635742188], [new Date(1346976701000), 3989.92456054688], [new Date(1346976711000), 3980.75903320313], [new Date(1346976721000), 3965.29516601563], [new Date(1346976731000), 3986.69189453125], [new Date(1346976741000), 4004.6005859375], [new Date(1346976751000), 4020.123046875], [new Date(1346976761000), 4023.11865234375], [new Date(1346976771000), 4035.29150390625], [new Date(1346976781000), 4052.357421875], [new Date(1346976791000), 4038.36108398438], [new Date(1346976801000), 4062.8505859375], [new Date(1346976811000), 4064.73315429688], [new Date(1346976821000), 4051.31616210938], [new Date(1346976831000), 4021.96899414063], [new Date(1346976841000), 3997.01147460938], [new Date(1346976851000), 3977.91577148438], [new Date(1346976861000), 3974.49682617188], [new Date(1346976871000), 3961.978515625], [new Date(1346976881000), 4001.267578125], [new Date(1346976891000), 4007.3154296875], [new Date(1346976901000), 3996.1484375], [new Date(1346976911000), 4042.66772460938], [new Date(1346976921000), 4022.11743164063], [new Date(1346976931000), 4019.2509765625], [new Date(1346976941000), 4023.57934570313], [new Date(1346976951000), 3999.955078125], [new Date(1346976961000), 3998.23413085938], [new Date(1346976971000), 3983.35693359375], [new Date(1346976981000), 3977.345703125], [new Date(1346976991000), 3990.88525390625]];
                var chartData = { label: marker.label, data: dq };
                kcArray.push(chartData);
                //alert(dq);
                //$('#content').html(marker.data);
            });
            // and plot all we got
            $.plot($('#content'), kcArray);

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Charts/GetPowerChart',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: onDataReceived
        });

    });  

</script>
```

Whenever I load this my graph loads great

However whenever I change dq to marker.data nothing works the label works but the data will not load on the graph the data I entered inside the manual load and marker.data is exactly the same:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var kcArray = [];


        function onDataReceived(series) {

            $.each(series, function(i, marker) {
                var dq = marker.data;
                var chartData = { label: marker.label, data: dq };
                kcArray.push(chartData);
                //alert(dq);
                //$('#content').html(marker.data);
            });
            // and plot all we got
            $.plot($('#content'), kcArray);

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Charts/GetPowerChart',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: onDataReceived
        });

    });  

</script>
```

Can someone please help???

Comment: Most likely, the manual dq and marker.data look the same, but really aren't - can you show us the exact contents of marker.data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to fix it:

The JS:

```js
var data24 = [];

function onDataReceived(seriesData) {
  //alert(seriesData.seriesData);
  var p = $.plot(placeholder, seriesData.seriesData, options);
}

var fullDate = new Date();
var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1); 
var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getDate() + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear(); 


$.ajax({
  url: '/Charts/LineChart?SeriesToGraph=5,7,9,11&DatePull=' + currentDate,
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: onDataReceived
});
```

Here is what I did on the MVC Side:

```c#
public JsonResult LineChart(string SeriesToGraph, string DatePull) {
  chartJson js = new chartJson();
  IList<testData> dt = new List<testData>();

  //string DatePull = "09-12-2012";            
  //string SeriesToGraph = "1,2,3,4";

  foreach (var series in SeriesToGraph.Split(',')) {
    IList<clsGraphData> dc = _mainRepository.graphRepository.GetGraphData(int.Parse(series), DatePull);
    IList<string[]> rw = new List<string[]>();

    string Label = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in dc) {
      Label = item.Name;
      rw.Add(new string[] { DateTime.Parse(item.DatapointDate.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), item.DatapointValue.ToString() });
    }

    testData data = new testData();
    data.label = Label;
    data.data = rw;

    dt.Add(data);
  }
  js.seriesData = dt;

  return Json(js, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```